# Group rows on condition PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

```
SELECT t."Column1", t."Column2", CASE WHEN MAX(t."Column3") = 5 THEN 5 END AS "Column3"
FROM "Table" AS t
GROUP BY t."Column1", t."Column2"
```

I have a table with repeated `Column1` and `Column2` pairs, let's say this is '*many-to-many*' table. Also, I have there one extra integer column - `Column3`.
What I want is select conditionally grouped rows, like
1). If pair of `Column1` and `Column2` have several records contains `5` value among others - then it should be grouped into one row with `Column3: 5`;
2). Else, I don't want rows to be grouped.

How that can be achieved? My query do the first requirement but I have no idea how to implement the second. Is it possible via CTE, or subquery only?

Table data example:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3
'a'       'b'       1
'a'       'b'       2
'a'       'b'       5
'a'       'c'       1
'a'       'c'       2
```

Desired result:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3
'a'       'b'       5
'a'       'c'       1
'a'       'c'       2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses `not exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where
    column3 = 5
    or not exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.column1 = t.column1
            and t1.column2 = t.column2
            and t1.column3 = 5
    )
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select column1, column2, column3
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        count(*) filter(where column3 = 5) over(partition by column1, column2) cnt_5
    from mytable t
) t
where column3 = 5 or cnt_5 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
with has_5 as (
  select distinct column1, column2
    from your_table
   where column3 = 5
)
select column1, column2, 5 as column3
  from has_5
union
select t.column1, t.column2, t.column3
  from your_table t
 where not exists (select 1 from has_5
                    where column1 = t.column1 and column2 = t.column2)
;
```

Comment: not tried this, just satisfied with @GMB solution. thanks!